# Is it possible or even allowed to implement QoS on server and client? Live555

Tags: client, reporting, rtsp, live555, qos

I have been looking at RTSP of Live555 and seems they are following RTSP as per definition form IETF. So far they seem to have reporting for transmission (data sent) on the server end, and reception (data received ) client end.

I am wondering is it possible to implement send/receive statistics (QoS) reports for both the client and the server? I am in a requirement to gather statistics of data sent and received at both the server and the client.

I am new to Live555 and the documentation is pretty obscure in this aspect so any direction is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the client side, a example could be found from [openRTSP](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/) test programs.
openRTSP could display QOS client information :

> Outputting QOS statistics
>
> Use the "-Q" option to output QOS ("quality of service") statistics
>   about the data stream (when the program exits). These statistics
>   include the (minimum, average, maximum) bitrate, packet loss rate, and
>   inter-packet gap. The "-Q" option takes an optional
>    parameter, which specifies the length of the
>   time intervals - in multiples of 100ms - over which the "minimum,
>   average, maximum" statistics are computed. The default value of this
>   parameter is "10", meaning that these statistics are measured every 1
>   second (i.e., 10x100ms).

For the server side, you can get the QOS informations from the RTPSink::transmissionStatsDB().